# Flash movie does not show all embedded font style

Tags: flash, adobe

I exported a flash movie from Apple flash CS4 with one font and different styles like bold, bold it, regular and italic. I followed the steps on http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/How+to+use.
The export protocol says all fonts are embedded. But flash player does not show the four font styles - only the style of the first letter!

A friend made a test: Embedding with Windows flash CS4 works.

Which mistake did I do? (No - I do not want to buy windows!)

Answer (score 0):

When there's a PC/Mac problem with fonts, in my experience it's usually due to a difference in the name of the fonts - like one platform wants you to use the bold version of "Arial", and the other wants "Arial Bold" or "Arial Strong", or the bold version of "Arial Regular", or so on. That's just a guess, but you might try some different combinations and see if something works.